# decorator on object instance kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to convert my Java android code to Kotlin but for my networking functions i use an decorator to override some function to added soem header functions.

```
DefaultJsonRequest getRequest = new DefaultJsonRequest<FeedModel>(
                Request.Method.GET, url,null, responseListener,
                responseListener,new FeedDetailReader()) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("","");
                params.put("","");
                return params;
            }
};
```

How can i reproduce this in Kotlin?.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in Kotlin for anonymous classes is this:

```
val someVariable = object : SomeObject(someConstructorArg) {
    override fun someOverrideFun() {}
}
```

Android Studio should just convert your code automatically for you if you paste it into a Kotlin file.